# How to change file permissions on Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod

When I clear Linux caches, I use this:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

It tells me: `Insufficient permissions`

Then I inspect the file `drop_caches` with:

```
ls -l /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

and I get this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0  1月 22 01:21 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

So I use:

```
chmod 777 /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

to change the file permissions, but insufficient permissions is printed again.

Current user is `root`, how can I change the permissions of this file?

Answer (score 0):

As root, `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` should work. Run `whoami` to make sure you are root.

If not, type `sudo -i` or `su` to open a root shell where you can run these commands.

Comment: PLZ test this "echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches"

Comment: If you're running the command as root, the `sudo` is unnecessary.

Comment: YES , It prints root  after run "whoami"

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Permissions on `/proc` nodes are defined in the kernel, and cannot be changed at runtime.

Comment: I am a new one at Linux , could you  tell me what should I do ?

Comment: @Y.yeli What you _should_ do? Don't use drop_caches. The only effect it has is reducing performance until the cache refills.

Comment: That's depressed.  I run "git pull" just , It prints this: error: cannot fork() for git-remote-https: Cannot allocate memory ,Then  I check the memary:             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          256M       132M       123M       8.6M         0B        45M
-/+ buffers/cache:        86M       169M
Swap:         128M       128M         0B

Comment: The only thing that I can do is restart the VPS ,right ?

Comment: @Y.yeli There is something wrong with your machine. Contact your host.